# How to prepend a string to a string variable in a for loop without changing the loop structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have a for loop like this:

```
var rows;
var len = z[0].length;
for ( var i = len; i--; ) {
     rows += "<tr><td>" + z[0].Marketer + "</td><td>";
 }
```

How can i prepend instead of append the current row to this string WithOUT changing the for loop structure?

```
var rows;
var len = z[0].length;
for ( var i = len; i--; ) {
     rows (prepend) "<tr><td>" + z[0].Marketer + "</td><td>";
 }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like this:

```
rows = "<tr><td>" + z[0].Marketer + "</td><td>" + rows;
```

Comment: Simple and straight to the answer. Plus one

Comment: There might be other issues as well, like  accessing `z[0].length`, treating `z` like an array, and `z[i].Marketer`, treating `z`  like an object -- but at any rate your answer will do fine, ignoring any possible issues of the `z` object's usage.